# Divisibility proof of "If $a\mid b, \text{and}, a\mid c, \text{then}, a \mid (mb + nc)$

Tags: solution-verification, arithmetic, integers

I would just like to make sure my proof of the statement:

> If $a,b,c,m,n \in \mathbb{Z}, a\mid b, \text{and}, a\mid c, \text{then}, a \mid (mb + nc)$

Makes sense and is correct.

---

If $a \mid b$ and $a \mid c$ then $\exists q,k \in \mathbb{Z}$ so that $b = qa$ and $c = ka$. We can substitute for $b$ and $c$ to see $mb + nc = m(qa) + n(ka)$. It is then clear that $a \mid mqa$ and $a \mid nka$. Since $a$ divides both products it also divides their sum, $a \mid (mqa + nka)$, or equivalently, $a \mid (mb + nc)$ $\square$

Comment: Yes this works, but you could also say that $mb+nc=mqa+nka=a(mq+nk)$ since addiction and multiplication in $\Bbb{Z}$ is distributive and then it's obvious that $a|a(mq+nk)\Leftrightarrow a|(mb+nc)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. Alternatively, you could prove the following two statements separately:

1. If $a\mid b$ then $a\mid ka$ for any $k\in\mathbb Z$.   (if $a$ divides a number then it divides any multiple of that number).
2. If $a\mid b$ and $a\mid c$ then $a|b+c$ (if $a$ divides two numbers then it divides the sum of those two numbers).

Now suppose that $a|b$ and $a|c$. Then, by $(1)$, we know that $a|mb$ and $a|nc$, so by $(2)$, we know that $a|mb+nc$.